# Declaring variables in pl/sql block

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, syntax-error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func(str IN NVARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER IS ret_val NUMBER(9);
DECLARE  new_str NVARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
....
```

This gives error that `encauntered symbol "declare" ....`

If remove "DECLARE", function compiled success.

Can you tell me why no need here using word   `DECLARE`  ?

When need to declare variables, before `BEGIN` statement must something like this, right?

```
DECLARE
variable_1 type;
variable_2 type;
BEGIN
.....
```

Where I am wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An anonymous PL/SQL block is defined by the keywords DECLARE, BEGIN, EXCEPTION, and END.

```
DECLARE
  l_message VARCHAR2 (100) := 'Hello';
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_message); 
END;
```

An named PL/SQL block, like a function, a procedure or a package, does not need a DECLARE keyword:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_hello
IS
  l_message VARCHAR2 (100) := 'Hello';
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_message); 
END p_hello;
```